# .Net Web API and Autofac - HTTPRequestMessage VS HTTPRequestBase

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am using Autofac for DI with a .Net Web API project. The dependencies to API controller are injected using Autofac. One of these dependencies needs to look at request headers.

So I registered current HTTP Context and resolved HTTPRequestBase object. The code looks at headers and creates a new object X (by making a connection to datastore). I put this object X HTTpContextBase.Items to be used later, so that I dont need to connect to datastore.

The project also does parameter binding using HTTPParameter Binding. The parameter that needs to be bound is this new object X I created. But from HttpParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync, I am not able to access current HTTPContext. But parameter binding can access HTTPRequestMessage.

Is there any way that I can register HTTPRequestMessage to Autofac. Or any way to access HTTpContextBase.Items while doing parameter binding.